# How to transform not POT images into POT bitmaps to use them on textures for openGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

Im doing my first steps on OpenGL-ES. Atm i can load Power of Two (POT) textures on a square polygon that i can rotate and zoom on the screen. If i try to load a non POT png, then, the texture appears white.

What I need to do some trick to transform non POT textures into POT bitmaps to fill the texture of my square polygon. How can i transform them into POT bitmaps?

This is the actual code i have to load textures:

FROM ASSETS DIR:

```
    String imagePath = "radiocd5.png";
    AssetManager mngr = context.getAssets();
    // Create an input stream to read from the asset folder
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        is = mngr.open(imagePath);
    } catch (IOException e1) {  e1.printStackTrace();   }

    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.radiocd5);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

FROM RES/DRAWABLE:

```
    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.radiocd5);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

Comment: With respect to the white issue, are you remembering explicitly to disable mip mapping when using non-pot textures?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to resample the image, sizing it to a power of two (POT). Google 'image resampling' and be ready to face some heavy math;) Lanzcos resampling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling is one of several ways you might consider. Bilinear interpolation also does pretty well.